# Indexing in magento2.0

Tags: magento2

How to do indexing in Magento2.0?

I cant find any option there? I tried both Update by schedule and Update on Save. But no luck

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reindex magento2 using command

for example your magento root directory is "magento2"

Your path like

> var\www\html\magento2\bin

Now You have to enter command

> sudo php magento indexer:reindex

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: I am using it in my local wamp server

Comment: where you have installed wamp in which path? and also give path to the magento 2 root folder.

Comment: I installed in `wamp/www/2.0/` indexing can not be done through interface? can be done only through command line?

Comment: i think it is bug in magento 2. i also find but not get answer through interface. so it is better idea to do through cammand till we get through interface.

Comment: okay let me try +1 for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can't do indexing manually using admin panel in magento 2.

The best way to do indexing is using command line.
First go to your magento/bin path and hit command

`sudo php magento indexer:reindex`